# wordpress link home page to different page

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have created html pages and trying to convert into wordpress theme,how to link html one page to other page in wordpress menu bar
sample code :

`<a href="<?php bloginfo('url')?>/feature.php">Features</a>`

this code is not working,it 's showing page not found.how to make this link in wordpress using php code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use pages or posts for this, i prefer pages.
Create new pages or posts and get their ID.
For linking its:

### Get link with this:

```
get_permalink( $yourPostOrPageID ); // only get; not echo
```

### Otherwise

- Wordpress homepage link:

  ```
   get_bloginfo('home');
  ```
- Category or custom taxonomy term link:

  ```
   get_term_link( $term, $taxonomy );
  ```

Answer (score 1):

1. Firstly Create Page "Features" from wp-admin.
2. Create template for this page.
   http://codex.wordpress.org/Stepping_into_Templates
3. To set this page in menu Go in "Menu" section in WordPress.
   http://codex.wordpress.org/Appearance_Menus_Screen
4. To view this menu in fronted use wp_nav_menu()

Comment: how to cretae page from wp-admin?. and i have used wp_nav_menu() its showing order by vertically menu. i need to use my menu from home page.

Answer (score 1):

Take example template from your theme. 
This is file in theme ending with -page.
Change template name in head of a file. 
Then remember about `the_loop` all should be inside a loop to work correctly with many pages. 
Put html there, also in `header.php` attach css to this html. 
Page structure is like, `header` in the up, then `page` and then `footer`. 
Remember to preserve good html structure - divs beginning and ending. 
Then you create a page with content ( which is presented in `the_loop` ) , which has its own url address. 
You can set url naming of pages in `settings -> permalinks`, you may need to write to `.htaccess` file. 
Then you have direct url to page. You can use it in code like this:

```
echo bloginfo('url'). 'nameofpage';
```

All to do is create a template and assign it to page ( on page edit `page template` option ).

Comment: echo bloginfo('url'). 'nameofpage'; not working still any other source please do help